# jspm workflow for creating front-end libraries

Tags: javascript, build, ecmascript-6, systemjs, jspm

What is the current recommended practice for converting a library written in *TypeScript* to ES5?

JSPM documentation seems to be geared toward web apps (i.e. with `jspm bundle-sfx`).

All the articles I can find on Google seems to be assuming a web app workflow rather than a library workflow.

My projects have the following setup:

- It depends on `react`, `flux` and `jquery`, all installed through `jspm` and are properly configured in `config.js`
- The source `.tsx/.ts` files are located in a `src/` tree, along with their corresponding transpiled `.js` files
- I am able to create a bundle with `jspm bundle`, however, this still requires the end user of my library to be using SystemJS

What I want is to bundle the entire tree under `src/` into a single file *without* libraries such as `react` or `jquery`. How can I do this?

So far I've tried `jspm bundle src/<MY_MAIN.js> - react - jquery <OUT.js>` this works, but user still need a module loader to interact with exported symbols in `MY_MAIN.js`. I would also like to provide users with an option to manually import my library with `<script>` tags. self-executed bundles do not seem to work. No symbol is accessible globally once loaded through the `<script>` tag and I cannot exclude the framework code.

Comment: See [JSPM: Publishing Packages](http://jspm.io/docs/publishing-packages.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are basically three approaches that I want to highlight, targeted at different end-user workflows

## 1. the `<script/>` tag approach

Here, create an entry `.ts` file that exports the main symbols of the library like so:

```
// Main.ts
import {MyLib} from "./components/MyLib";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

/**
 * browser exports
 * note, typescript cannot use interfaces as symbols for some reason, probably because they are not emitted in the compiled output
 * running `jspm bundle-sfx` results in the code here being accessible in <script /> tag
 */

(function (window) {
    window.MyLib = MyLib;
    window.React = window.React || React;
    window.ReactDOM = window.ReactDOM || ReactDOM;
})(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {});
```

then run `jspm bundle-sfx Main.js my-lib.sfx.js`, the same works for `browserify`, except we have to use `commonjs` style `require()` instead of ES6 style `import`

## 2. Concat & Minify src files through regular `gulp/grunt`

this should just be the good old workflow we are all familiar with

## 3. Assume ES6 compatibility for apps that will use the library

Distribute the code as ES6/TS along with `.d.ts` and assume the user will also use jspm/system or eventual ES6 module loader approach to load your module